# Deserialize binance API in json

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization

I'm trying to Deserialize data from binance API. The format in the website is:

```
{
  "lastUpdateId": 82930322,
  "bids": [
    ["0.09766700","12.64700000",[]],
    ["0.09766600","0.19500000",[]],
    ["0.09765800","0.30300000",[]],
    ["0.09765600","3.50000000",[]],
    ["0.09765500","0.14900000",[]]
  ],
```

I try to save the data to:

```
public string NameOfCoin { get; set; }
public string[][]  bids { get; set; }
```

And I get exception that it can't read the `[]` in the end of the array. I tryed also for a diffrent format like float or string withour array and it dosent work.

Comment: It appears that you've posted partial code and data. Please show your complete example. Also, please use the formatting help to format your code as code by adding at least 4 spaces to the start of each line. (if your data is down completely, it is invalid json which is likely part of your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the simplest solution is to change the type of your `bids` property from `string[][]` to `object[][]`.  That will allow the deserialization to succeed, but working with the `bids` array will be awkward.  You will have to do type checking on the items and cast them appropriately when you use them.

A better idea is to filter out the unwanted empty array values during deserialization.  You can do that with a custom `JsonConverter` (assuming you are using Json.Net -- your question did not indicate what JSON serializer you are using).  Here is one that should do the job:

```
class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JArray rows = JArray.Load(reader);
        foreach (JArray row in rows.Children<JArray>())
        {
            foreach (JToken item in row.Children().ToList())
            {
                if (item.Type != JTokenType.String)
                    item.Remove();
            }
        }
        return rows.ToObject<string[][]>(serializer);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

To use the converter, mark the `bids` property in your class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomConverter))]
public string[][] bids { get; set; }
```

Then you can deserialize to your class as usual and it should "just work".

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TajQt4