# Can not deserialize JSON with array in array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How I should deserialize below JSON?

```
{
    "lastUpdateId": 131537317,
    "bids": [
        ["0.08400000", "0.54300000", []],
        ["0.08399800", "0.70800000", []],
        ["0.08399400", "1.22700000", []],
        ["0.08399300", "0.61700000", []],
        ["0.08399100", "0.35400000", []]
    ],
    "asks": [
        ["0.08408300", "0.09100000", []],
        ["0.08408400", "5.55300000", []],
        ["0.08408600", "0.71800000", []],
        ["0.08408900", "0.14500000", []],
        ["0.08409000", "0.15100000", []]
    ]
}
```

I use classes like below. `Ask` and `Bid` are the same.

```
Order deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(timeServer);

public class Order
{
    public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }

    public List<Bid> bids { get; set; }

    public List<Ask> asks { get; set; }
}

public class Bid
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I have error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'WebApplication2.Models.Bid' because the type requires a JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error
>   either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or
>   change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a
>   collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can
>   be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be
>   added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   'bids[0]', line 1, position 35.

Comment: Where is `Items` supposed to magically come from? There is no `Items` in the JSON. Re-read the message, it's very clear. You'll need an array (it'll have to be `object`, since the entries are either strings or empty arrays [bizarrely]) or a list, not `Bid`.

Comment: past your jason on http://json2csharp.com/ to get classes

Comment: Looks like issue with Bid, as it should have just List<string> whereas value has something different.

Comment: @LeszekRepie that tool isnt very useful anymore.  Visual Studio has this built in since 2015

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251048/deserialize-binance-api-in-json or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47879889/json-net-converting-array-of-arrays-with-different-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better class to represent your JSON is:

```
public class Order
{
    public int lastUpdateId { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> bids { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> asks { get; set; }
}
```

As @maccettura mentioned in his comment `Bids` and `Asks` are `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`

[image]